Use webpack built wasm project within hugo
I have been trying to get my wasm app running on my Hugo site for the past week, and have run into a dead end.
After building everything with webpack, my dist directory looks like this:
project/dist ❯ ls
0.bootstrap.js                    bootstrap.js                      index.html
2d159acca5a4d5967245.module.wasm  bundle.js
4ac1e69088fb0b58205f.module.wasm  effbba6233883be097ea.module.wasm

index.html loads bootstrap.js like this:
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

Everything works perfectly if I run python -m http.server in project/dist. All I want is to be able to call the functions defined in the wasm from a hugo page.
First, I copied index.html to layouts/shortcodes/game_2048.html so I can add it to an article.
I then copied everything in the original dist directory to assets/solve2048_dist and referenced the js file in solve_2048.html like so
{{ $js_2048 := resources.Get "js/solve2048_dist/bootstrap.js"  }}
<script src="{{ $js_2048.Permalink }}"></script>

When I run the hugo server, I get 404 errors whenever bootstrap.js imports 0.bootstrap.js or the wasm files.
It seems like hugo just needs to make the js/solve2048_dist/* files available to the fetch API, but I might be missing something.
I tried piping the output of resources.Get into js.Build, but that doesn't seem to work as the esbuild hugo uses doesn't support wasm. I was told by someone else to build manually and to reference that output, which is what I'm currently trying to do.
